# Why is dividing giving similar times to multiplicating?

Tags: python, optimization

I was trying to show that Multiplicating is way faster than Dividing and by how much, but its always showing similar times, am I doing something wrong?

```py
import warnings
import time

warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=DeprecationWarning) 

start_time = time.clock()
for i in range(1, 1000000):
    x = i + i * 0.33;
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.clock() - start_time))

start_time = time.clock()
for i in range(1, 1000000):
    x = i + i / 3;
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.clock() - start_time))
```

Output is:

```
--- 0.62449341 seconds ---
--- 0.6291437290000002 seconds ---
```

This was my first post, so I cant upvote, still, thank you very much for the answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: 
As you can see, multiplication is not necessarily the faster operation here. Depends on how the compiler optimizes the things.

--

Most probably, rest of the calculation is adding up to time.

When tried with only multiplication / division

```
In [2]: %timeit [i * 0.33 for i in range(1_000_000)]                                            
123 ms ± 1.54 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [3]: %timeit [i * 1/3 for i in range(1_000_000)]                                             
150 ms ± 9.99 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [4]: %timeit [i /3 for i in range(1_000_000)]                                                
102 ms ± 1.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Try without sum / assignment operations

```py
In [5]: %timeit x = 5                                                                           
16.9 ns ± 0.0717 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000000 loops each)

In [6]: %timeit  5                                                                              
10.8 ns ± 0.0264 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000000 loops each)

In [7]: %timeit x =  10 / 2                                                                     
16.9 ns ± 0.0986 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000000 loops each)

In [8]: %timeit 10 / 2                                                                          
10.7 ns ± 0.0103 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case multiplying is 0.004650319 seconds (4.65 ms) faster. The reason why the difference is not very obvious is due to the for loop taking time.

---

Using timeit:

```
python -m timeit "0.001 * 100"
>>> 100000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0111 usec per loop

python -m timeit "100 / 1000"
>>> 10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0328 usec per loop

python -m timeit "for i in range(10000000): pass"
>>> 10 loops, best of 3: 338 msec per loop
```

From this is is clear that multiplication is about 3 times faster than division. In addition, the for loop itself is taking much more time than the multiplication or the division ops.

---

To solve this you should put the timing inside of the for loop:

```py
total_time = 0

for i in range(1, 1000000):
    start_time = time.clock()
    x = i + i * 0.33;
    total_time += time.clock() - start_time

print("--- %s seconds ---" % total_time)
```

Comment: Note: [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) is most commonly used for timing of short parts of code.